# How to save a file from webpage by prompting save as dialog box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, user-interface

In my application, after clicking on a hyperlink, the application creates a PDF file and downloads it automatically without prompting to save the file. I need a `Save As` dialog box prompting to save the file locally, that way I can select a directory every time I download the file. Please help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: The web page can't control this. It's a browser configuration issue. Look in your browser options.

Comment: thanks. but we cannot suggest the every end user to change the browser configuration.My requirement is, everytime when i click download it should prompt for a saveas dialog box, so that i can select folder structure everytime and save it. is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: ‎@Ram Am I understanding your question correctly? Your problem is that currently the file is downloaded automatically to the Desktop or something, instead of prompting for a location?

Comment: @Boann yes, you are rite.

Comment: ‎@Ram Then it is a browser configuration issue. You cannot change this server-side.

Comment: @Boann yes definitely its not on server-side. but is there any way to handle this on client-side scripting?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on browser support, If browser is support to view file then you can see file in browser and click save button to download it, otherwise, the browser will prompting a dialog box.

Comment: thanks, I understand it depends on browser. But my requirement is, everytime when i click download it should prompt for a saveas dialog box, so that i can select folder structure everytime and save it. is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: [http://www.techcoil.com/blog/php-codes-to-tell-browsers-to-open-the-download-dialog-box-for-users-to-download-a-file/]. This article may help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This... May Help You...

```
<a href="pdf_server.php?file=file_path">Download</a>

pdf_server.php

<?php
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"] .".pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

Comment: means that the generated pdf file should be saved to server, then the path for the file should be given to the href="pdf_server.php?file=file_path". is it so?

Comment: -1. As written, this script allows download of any arbitrary file on the server, such as files containing passwords or private data. Also, you don't need that loop; [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) exists. Also, this doesn't seem to answer the question as asked, if I'm understanding it correctly, but if that was the question, it would be a duplicate of many other questions anyway.

Comment: @Ram No saved to local disk, _file_path_ is your path of pdf file like _example.com/pdf_files/pdf_file_name.pdf_

Comment: @edcoder - thanks, i understood that. but <a href="pdf_server.php?file=file_path">Download</a> by clicking this will download a file from server rite. but in my case, when the pdf is generated it is not saved in the server.

Comment: @Ram Then how you gonna download the file? Without saving file in server?

Comment: @edcoder yes the file is not saved in the server. I am using a library to generate pdf file. When I click the hyperlink, it creates a pdf file and opens it in new browser tab in pdf format. from there I could save the pdf file. but for me, when I click the hyperlink the pdf file should be downloaded by prompting save as dialogbox.

Comment: @Ram **That's not what you said before!** You said the file is downloaded automatically. Now you're saying it's actually opened in a browser tab? Which is it?

Comment: @Boann That's why i'm add post this answer.

Comment: @Boann Initially it opened in new tab. Then I did some changes to my code to download the file without opening in new tab. There actually downloaded automatically with prompting for location to save.

Comment: @Boann ? he asked **save as dialog box prompting to save the file locally**, baesd on this my post is _wrong_?

Comment: @edCoder Yes it's wrong, because (1) it doesn't the problem; (2) it's poorly written code; and (3) it has a gaping security hole.

Comment: @edcoder - I tried your code, it didn't prompt for save as dialog box, It just downloaded the file.